# Add id to children and store them as array to list

Tags: javascript, parent-child, children

I have different buttons without id like this:

```
<div id="buttons">
  <button data-note="n1">One</button>
  <button data-note="n2">Two</button>
</div>
```

I cannot access them by `.button` since I have many, like 20 or so. Can I access them by their `data-note` attribute? `querySelector` selects the first one, second or all of them. Can I specifically select them, maybe put them an id?

What I actually want is to store the `data-note` as an Array, so have to convert that data into arrays as list to add to the HTML.

I supposed it is also possible without the id?
I might have to create for each button a function that by clicking them it stores that information as array into a list that I can access later if called, but I don't know how to select these children. If possible not by nodelist numbers, but by data, or if by nodelist then.

It might be a problem depending on the browser as they count 0,1,2 or 1,3,5... Is it possible to use `getElementById` and select a specific number of child?

To `addEventListener` I need to select each one of the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the notes data in a unordered list, then you can do the following:

```js
// Get all the buttons
let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

// Get the "clear" button as it has a special function
let clear = buttons[buttons.length - 1];

// Create an unordered list
let ul = document.createElement("ul");

// Iterate through the buttons
for (let button of buttons) {

  // Add the event listener to each button
  button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

    // Clear the unordered list if the clear button was pressed
    if (e.target === clear) {
      ul.innerHTML = "";
      return;
    }

    // For each button create a list item
    let li = document.createElement("li");

    // Set it's innerText attribute to be the data-note
    li.innerText = `${button.dataset.note} - ${e.target.style.backgroundColor}`;

    // Append it to the unordered list
    ul.append(li);
  });
}

// Append the list to the body
document.body.append(ul);
```

```css
button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Buttons Game</h2>
<p>Click the buttons to add them to the list, press clear to reset</p>
<button data-note="n1" style="background-color: red;">red</button>
<button data-note="n2" style="background-color: green;">green</button>
<button data-note="n3" style="background-color: orange;">orange</button>
<button data-note="n4" style="background-color: blue;">blue</button>
<button id="clear" style="color: black; border: 1px solid black;">clear</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried to add that, but when I try to print the unlisted list from the list created, I get an error message [object HTMLUListElement], so I am not sure if the error is in the function that says to print the unlisted list with all lists element notesrecorded.innerHTML = notesrecorded; // Im not sure yet if it worked to store the data

Comment: @MariaLindroos, I've updated my answer above. It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do, but the first snippet will get all the `data-note` and display them in an unordered list for you.

Comment: yes I am trying to get the data-note in an unordered list *of the buttons that are clicked*, in that order. I am trying to record the buttongs played, if you click red, green, orange, blue; then I need to add this list in a div, in the order that was clicked. Then I erase it and start it again, so I have to trigger that event to pass that list until I stop the event! Dont know if I made it clearer or more complicated

Comment: @MariaLindroos, please check my updated answer. Now you can click the coloured buttons and add them to the list, by pressing clear it will start again. Let me know it helped!

Comment: Haha, nice how you added CSS. The real code is a keyboard, so the clicks make sounds that are in other files, and so the data is for the name of the note (like A4), so you trigger the event of saving the notes by clicking Recording and with Stop you make the notes played appear, so has to stop the event for recording. Also recording again has to erase what was before. I will check your code in more detail though now

Comment: Yes, I wanted to make it look nice :) -- if this answered your question, then you can consider accepting it. Good luck with your keyboard project!

Comment: I have in the HTML the list  <ul id="rec-notes"></ul>, I tried to set it from the JS an innerHTML and pass a the result of the array created, but it didnt work. I have to check again the hierarchy of functions and events in my code or I think I will write it again because I DO need a loop, or boolean

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Output:**

[image]

**Steps:**

1) Use getElementsByTagName to store all the buttons into an array

2) Use a for loop to loop through the array

3) Use setAttribute to set the ids for all the buttons

4) Use the allButtons array as you wish since it contains all the buttons already, with their ids set.

**Code:**

```js
  var allButtons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  for (var i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++) {
    allButtons[i].setAttribute("id", "button-" + [i])
  }

  console.log(allButtons);
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <button data-note="n1">One</button>
  <button data-note="n2">Two</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Great way of simplifying. I am trying without the id by adding innertext as an array, though still not sure how to print it on screen since I keep getting the error [object HTMLUListElement]. Something of passing the element or calling the function im missing , so not sure if the function is storaging the clicked buttons

Comment: Thanks Maria Lindroos for the compliment! What is the new code that gives you the error?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with

```
var myNodes = document.querySelectorAll("button[data-note]");
```

This will assign to myNodes all buttons that contain data-note.
One of the properties of the array created's elements is "attributes" so you can search them easily with .find

Note:  I see that you are actually trying to record the clicks, in order, like a Simon game.  In that case you should have a hidden div on the page to store the data in, have every click call your event and that event gets the relevant control's data-note from the passed in e object to the function.  You can assign as many click events as necessary to the control and they will execute in reverse order, last one added runs first.